# PHP fully oriented object language

Tags: php

Why PHP is not considered a fully oriented object language like C sharp or Java?

I know PHP is more suited for web.

Comment: Because you can also write procedural code..

Comment: Those other languages are perfectly suited for the server side.  HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript are the languages of the web.

Comment: I know PHP is a server side language.

Comment: @Rizier123 I'm sorry for my lack of knowlodge but what you mean by procedural code ?

Answer (score 1):

To give a simple hello world comparison between c# and php, you'll see why php is called a scripting language:

PHP:

```js
<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>
```

C#:

```
namespace HelloWorld {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see with c# you need the namespace & class, with php it's all optional.